# Mount a folder on OpenVZ Container

Tags: openvz, share, directory

I'm struggling to get an NFS filesystem mounted on godaddy VPS. It looks like they are using OpenVZ, and I'm unable to mount an NFS filesystem share from one VPS to another. Does anyone know a way to share a folder between two or more machines, without root access to the host? I don't care if it's NFS, samba or anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting provider must explicitly enable [NFS client support](http://openvz.org/NFS) and/or [NFS server support](http://openvz.org/NFS_server_inside_container) for your container. Once that is done, you can use NFS normally.

You can also switch to a normal virtualization provider (e.g. not OpenVZ).